# How to specify current Dockerfile in docker-compose while using outside build context?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my project structure, two folders and two files.

**context
-- Dockerfile**

**test
-- test.sh**

Here is my context/Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get -y update
COPY test.sh /usr/local/bin/test.sh
```

In context directory, I can use `docker build -t test:1.0 -f ./Dockerfile ../test` to build docker image, and another way also works fine.( `cd` test directory and do `docker build -t test:1.0 -f ../context/Dockerfile .`)

But, I have some problems by using `docker-compose` in context directory, here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ../test
    image: test:1.0
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, always get this error:

> ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

I have tried `dockerfile: ./Dockerfile`, `dockerfile: ./`, and `dockerfile: .`, but none of them works.

I can only use this way `dockerfile: ../context/Dockerfile`, it works but I don't think it is the best way.

**Are there any better solutions that can specify current Dockerfile in docker-compose while using outside build context ?**

Comment: `../context/Dockerfile` is the thing to do

Comment: It looks ugly I think, and hard to read for other people.

Comment: In that case, you can move the Dockerfile